# Group membership error that has me pulling my hair out

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I am getting this error:

2011-04-09T18:13:17+00:00 app[web.1]: NameError (uninitialized constant Group::Membership):
2011-04-09T18:13:17+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/controllers/groups_controller.rb:25:in `show_members'

When I try and use the Show_members method in the groups controller. What have I done wrong?

## user.rb

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  require 'paperclip'
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :token_authenticatable, :confirmable, :lockable and :timeoutable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable, :confirmable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable
  has_and_belongs_to_many :roles
  has_many :articles
  has_many :ratings
  has_many :rated_articles, :through => :ratings, :source => :articles
  has_many :memberships, :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :groups, :through => :memberships
  ...
```

## membership.rb

```
class Membership < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :user_id, :group_id
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :group
  validates_uniqueness_of :user_id, :message => "You can only join one group!"
end
```

## group.rb

```
class Group < ActiveRecord::Base
  require 'paperclip'
  attr_accessible :name, :group_admin, :about, :location, :created_at, :avatar
  validates_uniqueness_of :name, :group_admin
  validates_length_of :name, :in => 4..40
  has_many :memberships, :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :users, :through => :memberships
end
```

## group_controller

```
def show_members # members page
    @group = Group.find(params[:id])
    @members = @group.users    <= THIS LINE IS THE ERROR
    @group_admin = User.find(@group.group_admin)
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html
      format.xml  { render :xml => @group }
    end
  end
```

## Update

```
def remove_user
    @membership = Membership.find(params[:user_id, :group_id])
    @membership.destroy
    authorize! :remove_user, @membership
    respond_to do |format|
        format.html { redirect_to(:back, :notice => 'User was successfully Removed.') }
      format.xml  { head :ok }
    end
```

I have this action in the groups_controller linked to in the show_members.html.erb
could the error be coming from this?

Comment: Please restrict the tags you use for a post to be only related to the programming language you're using.

Comment: oh, my mistake, what is group meant to be used for then?

Answer (score 1):

Oh my god. I just checked the git logs. Apparently, git decided not to add the memberships model file to the repo for some reason despite me doing git commit -a -m"blah". I thought the -a flag added everything?

Comment: you should really `git add .` (or `git add -p` if you only want to add *some* things) rather than `git commit -a`

Answer (score 0):

I don't see an error in the code you pasted, but judging from the error code you get, you must be having a constant value somewhere that cannot be accessed. Do you have any Group.Membership call somewhere in your code ? (maybe a module?) Maybe you meant to write group.membership or something. I really can't spot anything else :/

EDIT :

Btw, i see something that should be causing a problem as well :

```
@group_admin = User.find(@group.group_admin)
```

group.admin is a name as a i see in your validations and you're looking up for an id. It should be find_by_group_admin in this one.

Comment: If you remove the line that seems to be causing the problem, you don't get the same error ?

Comment: What is this line ? authorize! :remove_user, @membership. Please remove it for a test, and try again. Do you get the error ?

Comment: Well if I removed that line, it would break the show_members.html.erb as that view has a lot of variables that can only be accessed if the users in the current group are available. I added the remove_members action to my question.

Comment: I'm using can can to check authorization. That's not the error, but I'll remove it and try again.

Comment: Leon, don't just remove the innocent line then. Replace with something like "@members = Group.first.users". Just mock it to check if this really causes the problem.

Comment: Its throwing the same error. When I create the group, it should populate group.users with the user who created the group, right? Do I need to specifically add it?

Comment: Yes, it should be something like group.memberships << user.

Comment: @spyrosp Tried many different things for about an hour.. still nothing :(